# installing ghc in home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ghc, haskell

I am following the instructions http://sporkcode.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/installing-the-haskell-platform-in-ubuntu/ for installing GHC in Ubuntu.  And I want install it in my home directory.  I have successfully installed GHC, but when I try to install the Haskell platform, the configure script complains that GHC doesn't work.  This is because ld cannot find the GMP library, which is installed in ~/lib and GHC does not appear to pass LDPATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH to ld.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can issue an argument to ./configure of haskell-platform

```
Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-ghc=ARG          Use ARG as the path to ghc [default=autodetect]
  --with-ghc-pkg=ARG      Use ARG as the path to ghc-pkg [default=autodetect]
  --with-hsc2hs=ARG       Use ARG as the path to hsc2hs [default=autodetect]
```

Could one of these be what you are looking for?  To see all the available options do

```
./configure --help
```